# Docker FastAPI load balancing with NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, load-balancing, fastapi

I'm looking for some direction/critique on load balancing a web API I'm working on.

Here's what I am doing currently but am questioning:

1. I build the first image (the app) inside of mainApp using "*docker build -t app .*"
2. I build what's supposed to be the load balancer inside of the nginx folder using "*docker build -t nginx .*"
3. I run the images on separate containers in Docker Desktop on Windows; the app on port 8080 and nginx on port 8090.
4. When I load localhost:8090 in a web browser it does seem to switch between different process IDs but it's usually between 3 instead of just the 2 that I was attempting to declare in the nginx.conf file. This leads me to believe that it's not really setup correctly and the process ID returns are misleading. Is there a better way to test this?

**My file structure is as follows:**

> ```
> mainApp
>   app
>      main.py
>   Dockerfile
>   requirements.txt
>
> nginx
>   Dockerfile
>   nginx.conf
> ```

---

### And the code:

**main.py**

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Served From": str(os.getpid())}
```

**Dockerfile (inside mainApp)**

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

**Dockerfile (inside nginx)**

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream loadbalancer {
    server 192.168.80.12:8080;
    server 192.168.80.12:8081;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uvicorn` in the docker image [will by default use the same number of workers as CPUs available on the server](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker). The minimum numbers of workers by default is 2 (so if you only have a single core, two workers will still be launched to handle requests).

The worker pid will then change depending on which uvicorn worker handles your connection.

> WORKERS_PER_CORE This image will check how many CPU cores are
> available in the current server running your container.
>
> It will set the number of workers to the number of CPU cores
> multiplied by this value.
>
> By default:
>
> `1`
>
> You can set it like:
>
> `docker run -d -p 80:80 -e WORKERS_PER_CORE="3" myimage`
>
> If you used the
> value 3 in a server with 2 CPU cores, it would run 6 worker processes.
>
> You can use floating point values too.
>
> So, for example, if you have a big server (let's say, with 8 CPU
> cores) running several applications, and you have a FastAPI
> application that you know won't need high performance. And you don't
> want to waste server resources. You could make it use 0.5 workers per
> CPU core. For example:
>
> `docker run -d -p 80:80 -e WORKERS_PER_CORE="0.5" myimage`
>
> In a server
> with 8 CPU cores, this would make it start only 4 worker processes.
>
> Note: By default, if WORKERS_PER_CORE is 1 and the server has only 1
> CPU core, instead of starting 1 single worker, it will start 2. This
> is to avoid bad performance and blocking applications (server
> application) on small machines (server machine/cloud/etc). This can be
> overridden using WEB_CONCURRENCY.

Instead you can use `socket.gethostname()` to get the hostname of the serving docker container and see if that differs. Another option is to look at the log for the container itself - the image has the access log enabled by default (or output some content yourself to stdout) and see that both containers receive requests. You can [use `docker logs` to see the log of a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/).

Comment: Thank you - this is awesome. gethostname helped me see that it is indeed running in round robin mode once I spin up two different app containers with nginx load balancer.